# Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties error for structure declaration in Playground

Tags: swift

The declaration of the following code in Playground give the:

> "Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties"

```
struct Height {
    var heightInInches: Double
    var heightInCentimeters: Double

    init(heightInInches: Double) {
        self.heightInInches = heightInInches // here's the compile error
    }
    init(heightInCentimeters: Double) {
        heightInInches = heightInCentimeters * 2.54 // here's the compile error
    }
}
```

Please help me correct the syntax.

Comment: You need initialize both variables before init method returns, to avoid this you can declare this as lazy variables or declare as optionals, in fact i think the best approach for this is initialize only one variable and the other will be calculated one

Comment: Yes, one of your variables should be a computed variable. Also look at [NSMeasurement](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmeasurement)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you meant to do:

```
struct Height {

    var heightInInches: Double
    var heightInCentimeters: Double { return heightInInches / 2.54 }

    init(heightInInches: Double) {
        self.heightInInches = heightInInches
    }

    init(heightInCentimeters: Double) {
        heightInInches = heightInCentimeters * 2.54
    }
}
```

Note how `heightInCentimeters` is now a computed property rather than a stored property. (Alternately you could just get rid of `heightInCentimeters` if you don't need it.) Since `heightInInches` is a `var` property, this ensures that the two are always in sync.